# Subject of Infinitives for or to?

Tags: for, to-infinitive

> It is impossible **for** me to finish this work.
>
> It is impossible **to** me to finish this work.

Are both sentences correct?  (Or in the real world are both sentences spoken or written?)
Or is the only first sentence correct?

I'm sorry for asking a very basic question, I googled "subject of infinitives" but couldn't get answers.

In my country, in school tests, probably only first sentence is correct.

Comment: *for SUBJECT to VERB* is the correct form when *VERB* is in the infinitive and a *SUBJECT* is provided. Indeed, some grammarians hold that the construction with just the marked infinitive, no *SUBJECT*, is a reduced form of the *for* construction.

Comment: In OP's exact context, most if not all native speakers would only accept ***for***. But it's not obvious to me there's any structural difference in, say, [It's offensive to me to see such things](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22offensive+to+me+to+see%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and in that version I think I actually *prefer* ***to***. So I'm not convinced the choice of preposition is really a matter of "grammar" as such. It feels more like "idiomatic preference".

Comment: I would say the first one is correct, but I have no explanation for why should there be "for" instead of "to". "For" does not look like an appropriate preposition to "impossible" either.

Comment: Thank you for all helps.Anyway, I understand the usage of "to S " as a notional subject. Thanks.

Comment: And I appreciate editing my first POST!

Answer (score 7):

Unquestionably, OP's first example is "standard/correct" for what I assume is the intended meaning *(finishing this work is something that's impossible **for me to do myself**)*.

But that's not inherent in the context of constructions involving *impossible [preposition] me* and an activity expressed using an infinitive form. Consider, for example,...

> 1: *It seems impossible **for me** to put a man on Mars.*
>    2: *It seems impossible **to me** to put a man on Mars.*

Both versions are grammatically valid, but they mean different things.

In #1, ***for me*** modifies ***impossible***. Perhaps someone else can put a man on Mars, but apparently I can't.

In #2, ***to me*** modifies ***seems***. Perhaps putting a man on Mars seems possible to [some/all] other people.

Note that (probably for semantic reasons), when ***for me*** is used in close proximity to a verb like ***seems***, there's a strong tendency for us to interpret them in conjunction. Consider the situation if we slightly reshuffle the word order in #1 above...

> 1a: ***For me*** it seems impossible to put a man on Mars.
>   1b: *It seems **for me** impossible to put a man on Mars.*

I'll admit straight away that #1b is a bit clumsy, but it's not really "ungrammatical". The point is most people would interpret both as semantically equivalent to #2, when ***for me*** is moved closer to ***it seems***.

---

Having said all that, I do not believe *all* native speakers would *always* make this semantic distinction in *all* related contexts. That's to say there's a certain amount of ambiguity that cannot be fully resolved using "rules of grammar".

It often happens in such situations (i.e. - where different prepositions are at least "logically" credible) that if there are also different possible *interpretations*, idiomatic preference gradually settles on consistently assigning each different interpretation to one particular preposition.

Comment: Excellent answer, +1. Following on what you've said, in the OP's case *It seems impossible for me to finish this work* means "I can't finish the work" and *It seems impossible to me to finish the work* means "I don't think the work can be finished (with no mention of *who* is completing the work)".

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed explanation.I understand "to S to V" is also valid, and the difference between for preposition and to preposition in the sentence of infinitives.I appreciate your help.

Comment: @skypescenery29: Note that the *verb* can also be relevant. Even the *verb tense* can influence choice of preposition. For example, in Google Books, *It was stupid **of** me to [do something]* is over 30 times more common than the same using ***for***. But the unreal/future verb form *It would be stupid **for** me to [do it]* occurs almost half as often as the ***of*** version. So far as I'm concerned, both prepositions are perfectly grammatical and semantically equivalent, and only habit/local preference can explain the different choices people make.

Answer (score 0):

The way this sentence is constructed, the infinitive phrase **to finish this work** is functioning as an adverb (clarifying **is impossible**), and you can look at the sentence without that phrase:

> It is impossible for (to) me.

It's a rule of English usage that the preposition used in front of **me** in this case is **for**, so the first sentence is correct while the second one is incorrect usage.

As @FumbleFingers mentioned, the choice of preposition depends on what the adjective is, so in the case of **offensive**, the word should be **to**. (I think this is mostly a reflection of the implied agency in the statements: in the case of **impossible**, I am the agent, but in the latter case, the offense is happening *to me*.)

Comment: I think you're on shaky ground with that *It's a rule of English usage* bit. There's nothing wrong with *"That looks impossible **to** me"*, where *to me* modifies *looks* (in my judgement it's inherently impossible [for anyone]). As opposed to *"That looks impossible **for** me"*, where *for me* modifies *impossible* (***I*** can't do it, but perhaps others can).

Comment: I'd like to see your comments posted as answers. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Friendly Greasemonkey: I *think* there's a great deal of "established idiomatic preference" involved here, and I'm pretty sure chrylis is correct here in saying *choice of preposition depends on the adjective*. I'm not sure I'm competent to post a "generic" answer (I more than suspect there may not even *be* one). But I'll have a crack.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're correct in your example, but *that looks impossible **to** me* means something different. *In this case of this question*, **for** is the appropriate preposition.

Comment: @ chrylis: Undeniably. But OP could be reasonably sure which preposition was "appropriate" by comparing Google Books hits for [*impossible **for** me to do*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22impossible+for+me+to+do%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (326,000) with those for [*impossible **to** me to do*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22impossible+to+me+to+do%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (633). I don't disagree with anything you say (apart from the "rule" bit! :), but I think just saying "this wrong, that right" is of limited use here.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. I understand that the choice of prepositon depends on what the adjective is.I appreciate your help.